# how to use if condition with hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

For the following hyperlink I want to code that the image has a "src file(nt blank)" and this page coming after "1stTymStuCategorySelection.aspx" then it should navigate according to given url address if not it should prompt a error messege that "Guest access is denied". How can I do that please help me....

```
    <p>    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="Year1Sem1Sub1.aspx" runat="server" align="left">CIS 11301   Fundamentals of information systems</asp:HyperLink>
    <img src="images/guestPic.jpg" align="right"/>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery for this purpose.

`if( $('img').prop('src') )`  check with this kind of condition.

For previous URL:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
});
```

Comment: I'm using C# and ASP.net...

Comment: @Jiya I can see that through your code and tag, i am suggesting you to use Jquery in ASP.NET Web page

Comment: ok bt I'm not familiar with jquery... I'm a beginner in this field, can u help me how to use the jquery and where to use it????

Comment: @Jiya Jquery is most important in your asp.net career. first learn basics of it. http://jquery.com/ and http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp go through these sites and ask your senior regarding Jquery

Comment: k thanx 4 d references... :)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should do it on server side because its a security check and user can easily pass through it by disabling javascript in browser. or your application should not work if javascript is disabled.

**Update:**

change you markup like this

```
<img runat="server" id="imgGuestPic" src="images/guestPic.jpg" align="right"/>
```

and a label to show error

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="message"></asp:Label>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (imgGuestPic.Src ==null)
    {
        HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = null;
        lblMessage.Text = "Guest access is denied";
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ali: Then give an answer that does this. The OP didn't specify javascript and indeed *did* specify ASP.NET so telling them to do it serverside is a bit superfluous.

Comment: added some code now , but error showing mechanism depends on the application design. i've putted a lablel.